# Setting up a Cisco router for dial in access

Tags: cisco, router, modem

Our MPLS provider needs our routers to be setup with modems so that they can dial in and make config changes when necessary. I have connected the modem to the router (Cisco 2600) via the aux port. When I dial the # for the modem, it rings, but never answers. I'm guessing there's something in the router config that I need to setup, but I have no idea what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of modem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laziest way is almost certainly just to go:

```
async-1#terminal monitor
async-1#debug confmodem
Modem Configuration Database debugging is on
async-1#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
async-1(config)#line 1
async-1(config-line)#modem autoconfigure discovery
async-1(config-line)#
```

The real answer is set &S0=1 in your modemcap (well probably) Actually you probably want to look at the whole list of vendor init strings http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk801/tk36/technologies_tech_note09186a008009428b.shtml#specinitialcomm (that page also has some info on creating a chatscript and altering modemcaps)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to verify:

- you are use a cisco roll-over cable
- the modem speed
- what TTY number is your aux port
- configuration of your aux port

Additional information:  [Configuring a Modem on the AUX Port for EXEC Dialin Connectivity](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk801/tk36/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094bbc.shtml)

example:

```
line 65   
 modem inout
 speed 115200  
 transport input all
 flowcontrol hardware
 login
 password cisco
```